# Как скомпилировать прогу на C++ в BIN-файл (для запуска на компе без ОС)?

Tags: c++, компиляция, binary, binary-file

И возможно ли это? Есть ли каке-то компиляторы или ещё что-то?

Comment: Что подразумевается  под "комп без ОС"? PC-совместимая машина (x86/x64) , без установленной OC? Микроконтроллер? Что вы хотите от скомпилированной программы? Выводить байтики в порты, или, например, взаимодействовать с видеокартой?

Comment: Ну... Чтобы написать что-нибудь на смешанном коде (ассемблер и С++) и запустить это.

Comment: На "голом железе"

Comment: Компилируете и линкуете с флагом `-fno-stdlib`, линкуете со своим linker-script `-T my-linker-script` (он описывает распределение секций по адресам памяти) и делаете из .elf с помощью [objcopy](https://linux.die.net/man/1/objcopy) бинарный файл из нужных секций. Загрузка в память и запуск -- это отдельный вопрос, сильно зависит от железа